# Subset of numbers whose XOR has least Hamming weight

Tags: sets, arithmetic, coding-theory, xor

I'm given $n$ numbers (let's say of some 100 bits or so). Is there a way to find a non-empty subset xor of these $n$ numbers which has the least Hamming weight (no. of set bits) in better than $O(2^n)$ complexity? I was thinking of some trie based implementation but don't think that will work at all. Would a dynamic programming approach work by any chance? If possible, a hint would be nice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is known as *calculating the minimal distance of a (binary) linear code*, and is NP-hard, as shown by [Vardi](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/641542/). It is even NP-hard to approximate within any constant factor, as shown by [Dumer, Miccancio and Sudan](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~daniele/papers/DMS.pdf).

Comment: Just making sure here - `calculating the minimal distance of a (binary) linear code` is finding the minimum no. of set bits in the XORs of each nonempty subset of the binary representations?

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing.

Comment: Also, are there better algorithms (better than O(2^n)) used for calculating these distances?

Comment: That's possible, but unfortunately I'm not aware of any. Now that you know what to look for, you can find out on your own.